# GitHub - how can I create sub repositories?

Tags: github

I'm using GitHub through the web interface.

How can I how create sub repositories in GitHub?

Example: I've a repository where I store my Joomla! extensions. I would like to know how to create a sub repository for each extension?

Comment: You could look at using Submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

Comment: Do you mean simple folders/sub directories when talking about "sub repositories"? (Just adding that I'm not familiar with Joomla.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I forgot to specify that I only use the web interface.

I found my solution : simply create a new file with sub directory tree like this example : 
"maindir/subdir1/subdir2/file.txt". Github will create automatically the sub folders.

But it's not a good solution because it don't matter of the "issue" concept, issues are only attached to a "root" folder.

So finally, I've chosen an another solution. I use prefixs.

Thankz for your help.